# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: angular-cli

i have the following error runnning ng
nodejs version : 10.16.3
npm version : 6.9.0
i installed angular/cli : `npm install -g @angular/cli`
then i tried to create a new angular project i got this error (the same for `ng --version`)

```
    D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm>ng --version
    fs.js:114
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
        at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)
        at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
        at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:361:19)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:20)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\skima\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\request\index.js:18:15)

    D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things:

-Make sure your terminal/command window is running in admin mode.
-Run npm -v and node -v to make sure they both installed correctly
-Update to NodeJS 12
-Uninstall the global angular/cli and reinstall

The error seems to be indicating a permissions issue with reading from the node_modules folder where angular/cli is installed.

I also see that you're running the command prompt in your D drive but node_modules is installed on C. Try having them on the same drive.

Comment: my terminal is running in admin mode and i have tried many times uninistall / install.
i have installed nodejs (both 12 & 10) on my C:/ drive and i got the same Error

Comment: Alright, take a look through this thread, you may find it useful. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1830

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

> 1. npm cache clean --force
> 2. npm install -g npm@latest --force
> 3. npm cache clean --force
> 4. ng new project_name

Answer (score 0):

Shift your project to another drive and then run again. This is worked for me after spending hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yarn` instead of `npm`

yarn is a similar package manager as npm. Both go hand in hand.

```
$ npm install yarn -g
$ yarn
```